# How to compare all objects to each other.?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to compare two objects with *all* possible variations. How can I do that.

```
var _entries = new List<string>();

_entries.Add("Awesom");
_entries.Add("Awesom");
_entries.Add("Awesom");
_entries.Add("Awesom");

int count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < _entries.Count; i++)
{
    if (_entries[i].Equals(_entries[i - 1]))
    {
        count++;
    }
}

Console.Write(count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This one compares in *sequential order* but it should compare with *every possible* scenario.

The expected result should be `4` because there are `4` same objects in array.

Comment: You can use linq [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: Will the objects always be strings?

Comment: the objects can be real world objects as well. :

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*, [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8):

```
using System.Linq;

...

// No Sequential Order test
var _entries = new List<string>() {
   "Awesom",
   "Bar",
   "Awesom",
   "Awesom",
   "Foo",
   "Awesom",
   "Bar",   
};

int count = _entries
  .GroupBy(item => item)    
  .Sum(group => group.Count() - 1);
```

with a help of `GroupBy` we obtain `3` groups:

```
4 items of "Awesom"
1 items of "Foo" 
2 items of "Bar"
```

then we can just `Count` items in each group and `Sum` them: `(4 - 1) + (1 - 1) + (2 - 1) == 4` duplicates overall.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Spasiba vam ochen. :)

Comment: @Bears: You are welcome! Next time, please, provide the desired result (what is the expected `count` value)

Answer (score 0):

When you say *This one compares in sequential order but it should compare with every possible scenario.* I believe you are expecting value of **count = 16**. As by comparing with every possible values you'll have 16 combinations and as all the values are equal you'll get count as 16.

```
            var _entries = new List<string>();

        _entries.Add("Awesom");
        _entries.Add("Awesom");
        _entries.Add("Awesom");
        _entries.Add("Awesom");

        var query = from e1 in _entries
                    from e2 in _entries
                    where e1 == e2
                    select $"{e1} x {e2}";
        var count = query.Count();
```

Try printing values of query variable and you'll see all combinations.

Comment: As for final math (should `count` be `3` - my reading or `16` - your vision) it may vary (we don't know the the desired result). Your solution - cartesian join - has `O(n ** 2)` time complexity which can be *slow* on long input when `GroupBy` has `O(n)` time complexity

Comment: @Bears can you update the question with expected output, as what you are expecting to compare. Coz what I posted will compare everything in order. Do you mean you do not want to compare items at same index?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I wrote that coz I thought "every combination" with repetition is required. However, I agree it will be a performance bottleneck on large dataset.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough in my query. 

Well it must compare every item with every other item, though not if they have already been compared before. In another words I wanted to know if there are same objects in an array.

So @DmitryBychenko was right about that it should be grouped. 

thx you as well for your idea GauravMathur

Comment: Glad you got your answer :)